# can't do :joins without writing SQL code

Tags: sqlite, join, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't understand why this code works:

```
@ads = Ads.find(
   :all,
   :joins => "INNER JOIN ad_users u ON u.ad_users_id=ads.ad_users_id"
 )
```

and this one doesn't:

```
    @ads = Ads.find(
   :all,
   :joins => :AdUsers
 )
```

my classes are:

```
class Ads < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :ads_id
  belongs_to :AdUsers
end
```

and

```
class AdUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :ad_users_id  
  has_many :Ads
end
```

I use a sqlite database.
The sql generated for the join is:

```
SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" INNER JOIN "ad_users" ON "ad_users"."ad_users_id" IS NUL
```

can anyone help me? 
I know this is not a blocker, but I don't want to write the join SQL if I don't have to.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging in too deeply, I see a couple things that could be confusing the join logic.  First, I think you want your symbols to be lower cased with underscores on the joins clause and the associations.  (Eg, `:ad_users` instead of `:AdUsers`)  Also, the Rails conventions suggest singular classnames, though if you really want to you can get around this by specifying the class name explicitly:

```
class AdUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :ad_users_id
  has_many :ads, :class_name => 'Ads'
end
# ...and so forth
```

Unless you have a good reason, though, I'd suggest just using singular class names.

Comment: it says: Association named 'ad_users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: just saw, the sql generated is: SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" INNER JOIN "ad_users" ON "ad_users"."ad_users_id" IS NUL

Comment: Did you change both the joins clause and the associations?

Comment: The Rails conventions suggest singular class names (I just noticed yours are plural), and specifying associations in lowercase with underscores.  I haven't built a sandbox app to test anything out, but my guess is that your plural class names and camel-cased associations are confusing the join logic.

Comment: If you really don't want to change the class names, you might also try specifying the class name in the association.  (eg, has_many :ads, :class_name => 'Ads')